# Amsbook: Theoremstyles definition and remark identical?

Tags: fonts, amsmath, theorems

If I understand the documentation of the AMS classes correctly, then a theorem in the style "plain" should have bold heading and italic body text, in the style "definition", there should be bold heading and normal body text, and in "remark", there should be an italic heading and normal body text. This is described her in section 4: http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/amshelp/2.2/amshelp.pdf

Here, with amsbook, all headings look the same (in small caps), and there is no distinction between "definition" and remark in the body text.

Example:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rmk}{Remark}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
Here comes a theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{dfn}
Here comes a definition.
\end{dfn}
\begin{rmk}
Here comes a remark.
\end{rmk}
\end{document}
```

Is this behaviour correct or is there a problem in my LaTeX environment? I did not find any remarks in the documentation about a different behaviour for amsbook (then for, say, amsart). I also remember that, using an older version of TeXLive, the look of the headings was dependent on whether hyperref was loaded or not.

Comment: The `amsbook` class changes the theorem styles to suit the general setup of the class. In particular, all theorem headings are in "caps and small caps".

Comment: There is a difference between `amsbook.cls` (class) theorem styles and `amsthm.sty` (package) theorem styles. The ones you describe are the ones of `amsthm` and not of `amsbook`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **tohecz** mentions in his comment, the difference in the styles that you mention is the one of the `amsthm` package: however, the `amsbook` class internally defines the `remark` and `definition` styles in a different way. Here are the definitions:

```
\def\th@definition{%
  \let\thm@indent\indent
  \thm@headfont{\scshape}% heading font small caps
  \let\thmhead\thmhead@plain \let\swappedhead\swappedhead@plain
  \thm@preskip.5\baselineskip\@plus.2\baselineskip
                                    \@minus.2\baselineskip
  \thm@postskip\thm@preskip
  \upshape
}
\def\th@remark{%
  \let\thm@indent\indent
  \thm@headfont{\scshape}% heading font small caps
  \let\thmhead\thmhead@plain \let\swappedhead\swappedhead@plain
  \thm@preskip.5\baselineskip\@plus.2\baselineskip
                                    \@minus.2\baselineskip
  \thm@postskip\thm@preskip
  \upshape
}
```

As you can see, both styles behave exactly the same when using `amsbook.cls`.

Comment: Thanks, that difference was not clear to me. Meanwhile, I also looked at `amsclass.dtx` and at least understood some parts.